# How to block a key combination containing two base keys

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, how can I block a key combination like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Note that I have two base keys (F2 and F8) in it. Usually you can only block key combinations with one base key and up to three modifiers (Shift, Ctrl, Win).

With a small utility called [KeyCodes](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/utilities/KeyCodes.htm) I monitored what Windows sees when holding down Alt+F2+F8.
No surprise here.

[image]

I already tried AutoIt's function [`HotKeySet`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm), but unfortunately...

> **The following hotkeys cannot be set:**
>   [...]
>   Any global hotkeys a user has defined using third-party software, **any combos of two or more "base keys" such as '{F1}{F2}'**, and any keys of the form '{LALT}' or '{ALTDOWN}'.

**Q:** How can I block a key combination containing two base keys

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? If user presses `Alt-F2` it sees it, if the user presses `Alt-F8` it sees that too, but if user presses `Alt-F2-F8` it sees neither? Unfortunately the user won't press `F2` and `F8` exactly simultaneously and even if they did, the system will process them sequentially anyway. So at some moment there will be just `Alt-F2` or just `Alt-F8` and they'll take effect...

Comment: `In rare cases, its possible that a user presses Alt+F2+F8.` *That’s your* problem; you are trying to “fix” user error. There are plenty of keys that could cause undesired behavior when used incorrectly, e.g., `Del`, `Esc`, `Alt`+`F4`, but you don’t see people running out to find a way to prevent those from working. Unless people are pressing `Alt`+`F2`+`F8` frequently for some reason, then the unwanted behavior is just a way to reinforce learning to be more careful about what they press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this (untested) [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script will work :

```
$F2::
GetKeyState, state, F8
if state != D
SendInput {F2}
Return

$F8::
GetKeyState, state, F2
if state != D
SendInput {F8}
Return
```

Comment: Is there something like `$F2 down:: SendInput {F2 down}` and `$F2 up:: SendInput {F2 up}`? Here is a keyboard log made with [KeyCodes](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/utilities/KeyCodes.htm) where I hold down F2: [With AHK script](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Uy3nAf2i) running and [without AHK script](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HzE5prin) running. You see what I mean? (Whats this "spacebar" btw. O_o)

Comment: See the last boxed entry in [Hotkeys manual](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm). The example says `*LWin::Send {LControl Down}` and also `*LWin Up::Send {LControl Up}`. Reading that article can answer many questions.

Comment: It was a bit tricky but I got it to work, thx.

Comment: Better add the final script to your post, to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) a try, with this script:

```
pressed:= false
~!F2::
   pressed = true
   return
~*F2 Up::
   pressed = false
   return
!F8::
   if (pressed = "true"){
      return
   } else {
      Send {!F8}
   }
   return
```

It blocks <kbd>F8</kbd> when <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> is pressed, and let it go through otherwise. I tested it here, but I'm not sure it's the behaviour you exactly want...

Comment: Sry, this is not working. When I press ALT+F8 it only executes F8, but not the key combination I want.

Comment: I knew I forgot something. Can you try this corrected version?